# How can I change quantity in transfer

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.system

Good Day!!

I want to change add_balance in transfer

How can change quantity value in add_balance?

Ex) invalid operands to binary expression
('eosio::asset' and 'int')
add_balance( to, quantity - 100 , payer );

```
void token::transfer( const name&    from,
                      const name&    to,
                      const asset&   quantity,
                      const string&  memo )
{
    check( from != to, "cannot transfer to self" );
    require_auth( from );
    check( is_account( to ), "to account does not exist");
    auto sym = quantity.symbol.code();
    stats statstable( get_self(), sym.raw() );
    const auto& st = statstable.get( sym.raw() );

    require_recipient( from );
    require_recipient( to );

    check( quantity.is_valid(), "invalid quantity" );
    check( quantity.amount > 0, "must transfer positive quantity" );
    check( quantity.symbol == st.supply.symbol, "symbol precision mismatch" );
    check( memo.size() <= 256, "memo has more than 256 bytes" );

    auto payer = has_auth( to ) ? to : from;

    sub_balance( from, quantity );
    add_balance( to, quantity, payer );
}


void token::add_balance( const name& owner, const asset& value, const name& ram_payer )
{
   accounts to_acnts( get_self(), owner.value );
   auto to = to_acnts.find( value.symbol.code().raw() );
   if( to == to_acnts.end() ) {
      to_acnts.emplace( ram_payer, [&]( auto& a ){  
        a.balance = value;
      });
   } else {
      to_acnts.modify( to, same_payer, [&]( auto& a ) {
        a.balance += value;
      });
   }
  
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace eosio {
  struct asset {
    int64_t amount;
    symbol symbol;
  }
}
```

'quantity' is `eosio::asset` type that is a struct with two fields, amount and symbol. You can add or subtract value from amount directly (not recommended), or use asset type for calculation.

For example,

```
  // not recommended
  quantity.amount -= 100;

  // recommended
  quantity -= asset(100, quantity.symbol);
```

The reason to recommend the second way is that arithmetic operations between asset type will perform additional check like integer overflow or symbol equality.